# Bat file doesn't log when running from task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a bat file which restarts 2 services, and I have it run in task scheduler. If I run the bat file normally, I can see it logging in current directory as the bat file. But if I run it through task scheduler, I can see the bat runs, like in services window, I can see the services restarting, but it doesn't log anything.... Does anyone know what the issue is?

This is on windows server 2008 r2 64-bit.

Thanks

```
@echo off
SET waittimeseconds_sp_fix=15
SET logfilename_sp_fix="SPSearchFix.log"

echo %date% %time% - Restart starting >> %logfilename_sp_fix%


net stop SPTimerV4 >> %logfilename_sp_fix% 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo %date% %time% - WORKED - Stopped timer service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
) ELSE (
    echo %date% %time% - FAILED - Stopped timer service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
    exit
)

timeout %waittimeseconds_sp_fix%

net stop osearch14 >> %logfilename_sp_fix% 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo %date% %time% - WORKED - Stopped search service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
) ELSE (
    echo %date% %time% - FAILED - Stopped search service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
    exit
)    

timeout %waittimeseconds_sp_fix%

net start SPTimerV4 >> %logfilename_sp_fix% 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo %date% %time% - WORKED - Started timer service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
) ELSE (
    echo %date% %time% - FAILED - Started timer service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
    exit
)

timeout %waittimeseconds_sp_fix%

net start osearch14 >> %logfilename_sp_fix% 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo %date% %time% - WORKED - Started search service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
) ELSE (
    echo %date% %time% - FAILED - Started search service >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
    exit
)

timeout %waittimeseconds_sp_fix%

echo %date% %time% - Restart completed >> %logfilename_sp_fix%

echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
echo. >> %logfilename_sp_fix%
```

Comment: I figured it out, it was logging to system32 folder for some reason, but putting absolute path worked.

Comment: Try to set an  absolute path like C:\temp\foo.log for your logfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that the file is indeed being created, but in the "current directory" in which the batch runs.

You could execute

```
cd "c:\your\desired\directory"
```

as the first line after the `@echo off`

or

set the current directory as part of the scheduled task

or

define the filename with a complete pathanme.

btw

```
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
```

will for all intents and purposes always be true, as it means "if `errorlevel` is 0 or greater than 0".

You could use

```
if %errorlevel%==0 (
```

as a replacement.